# ShareThis icons resizing

Tags: html, sharethis

Please I need to know is there any way I can resize `ShareThis` sharing buttons on my website?

The problem is that it is very small when rendered on a mobile device. I need to make it larger.

Is it possible? or it is fixed and can not be changed since we are retrieving it from the server?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late reply.
I work at ShareThis, and I believe this is definitely solvable. We have our new SOP (Social Optimization Platform) for customizing your buttons at https://platform.sharethis.com. And you can install and customize your buttons there.

And if you are using reactjs, we recently released our reactjs plugin at https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharethis-reactjs, and you can customize your buttons through the configuration. Find more details in the documentation, and if you have more questions, I'm glad to help.